# php get associative array in place normal array as result of function

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

i create function who return normal array :

```
function get_list_array () {

                $list_object = get_list_objects();
                foreach ( $list_object as $every_object) {
                            $list_array[] = array (
                                          "wprm_$every_object->name" => array (
                                                     'name'         => _x("$every_object->label", , 'test'),
                                                      'singular_name' => _x("$every_object->name", , 'test'),));                                             
                      }

                        return $list_array ;

                         }

    var_dump ($list_array);

    array(2) { 
           [0]=> array(1) { ["object_1"]=> array(2) {
                                               ["name"]=> string(10) 
     "name_object1" ["singular_name"]=> string(15) "singular_name_object1" } } 
           [1]=> array(1) { ["object_2"]=> array(2) {
                                               ["name"]=> string(4) 
     "name_object2" ["singular_name"]=> string(10) "singular_name2" } } }
```

And i want the get in place just the associative array like this:

```
  array ("object_1" => array (["name"]=> string(10) "name_object1" 
  ["singular_name"]=> string(15) "singular_name_object1" } ,
                               "object_2" => array(2) {
                                           ["name"]=> string(4) 
  "name_object2" ["singular_name"]=> string(10) "singular_name2" } } }
```

any idea how i can modify my function in order the get the second output.

Comment: Can you just do print_r() instead of var_dump() ? It's too messy for me to understand it's structure.

Comment: sure , bellow the print_r output:
Array ( [0] => Array ( [object_1] => Array ( [name] => name_object1 [singular_name] => singular_name_object1 ) ) [1] => Array ( [object_2] => Array ( [name] => name_object2 [singular_name] => singular_name2) ) )

and i'm looking for something like this:
Array ( [object_1] => Array ( [name] => name_object1 [singular_name] => singular_name_object1 ) ) , [object_2] => Array ( [name] => name_object2 [singular_name] => singular_name2) ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrapping the array you actually want into another array by doing this:

```
$list_array[] = array(
    "wprm_$every_object->name" => array(
```

Instead, you should simply assign the new array to `$list_array` directly:

```
$list_array["wprm_$every_object->name"] = array(
```

Also, please think about how you indent your code, because *wow*. Your function *could* look like this:

```
function get_list_array () {
    $list_object = get_list_objects();

    foreach ($list_object as $every_object) {
        $list_array["wprm_$every_object->name"] = array(
            'name'          => _x("$every_object->label", , 'test'),
            'singular_name' => _x("$every_object->name", , 'test'),
        );
    }

    return $list_array;
}
```